# sorl-thumbnail syntax error

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm trying to use sorl-thumbnail in my app.

However, when I'm trying to start manage runserver the following error occures:

> File "/home/arie/PythonDevelopment/django-1.7/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/helpers.py", line 55
>      except ImportError, e:
>                         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'm using django 1.7 and python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3):

`except Exception, e` is [not valid syntax in Python 3 any more](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110).

Make sure you use an up-to-date version of `solr-thumbnail`, porting to Python 3 seems to have been [taken care of](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorl-thumbnail/11.12.1b) and the syntax error from your question is [not present in current master](https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail/blob/master/sorl/thumbnail/helpers.py#L66) any more.

Django 1.7 compatibility seems to have been [merged just recently](https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail/pull/308), so you may need to use `solr-thumbnail` from source for now.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install sorl.thumbnail` doesn't actually get you python 3 support. The current beta version is much more recent. To install this version, uninstall and reinstall with:

```
pip uninstall sorl.thumbnail
pip install -I sorl-thumbnail=11.12.1b
```

Use `pip show sorl.thumbnail` to check the correct version is installed.